# groovy how to test for environment existence inside config.groovy

Tags: groovy

best practice for testing for existence in tree structure?  For example testing for environment existence within a config file.  Current working example below.  Tried .hasProperty but couldn't get right object reference with in a tree structure like config.

```
def config = new ConfigSlurper(myenvironment).parse(new File('cfg.groovy').toURL())
def results = config.admin.server
 try {
    assert results.size != 0
    } catch...
```

cfg.groovy

```
environments {
    dev01 {
        admin {
            server = 'http://'
            port = '1'
        }
    }
    test {
        admin {
            server = 'http://'
            port = '1'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better way to do so, but you can check if the generated config object for the passed environment is empty:

```
def environments = '''
environments {
    dev01 {
        admin {
            server = 'http://'
            port = '1'
        }
    }
    test {
        admin {
            server = 'http://'
            port = '1'
        }
    }
}   
'''

def noExists = new ConfigSlurper('noExistEnv').parse(environments)
assert !noExists.isEmpty()
```

Since `noExistEnv` doesn't exists this execution shows:

```
Assertion failed: 

assert !noExists.isEmpty()
       ||        |
       |[:]      true
       false
```

Trying with an existent environment all works correctly:

```
def environments = '''
environments {
    dev01 {
        admin {
            server = 'http://'
            port = '1'
        }
    }
    test {
        admin {
            server = 'http://'
            port = '1'
        }
    }
}   
'''

def testCfg = new ConfigSlurper('test').parse(environments)
def result = testCfg.admin.server
// check that string is not empty
assert !result.isEmpty()
println result // prints "http://"
```

Hope it helps,